# Receiving "Path 'PUT' is forbidden" for RESTful Web Service Built on ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, rest

We have a super RESTful web service running well on two dev machines and a test 2k3 server.  We're trying to get the same service running on two other offsite dev boxes.  Whenever those two new, offsite boxes attempt a PUT request to 'Sessions' Resource (i.e Controller) (on localhost), IIS returns :

"Path 'PUT' is forbidden"

We turned on the MVC Route debugger and it appears that something between the front porch and the routing engine is gobbling up anything destined for http://localhost/OurAPI/Sessions.

We change the controller to UserSessions or even Session and problem goes away!

Any ideas?

Comment: Just to be sure: you said "'Sessions' Resource" and "http://localhost/OurAPI/Session"... is that a typo, or did the pluralization not match in your actual code?

Answer (score 0):

When it happens in my application is a routing problem, check your routes.